# Font size is decreased when exporting Crystal Report to PDF

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a font size issue in exporting crystal report using crystal report 13.0,the font size is decreased,so i need to increase it.i notice  that i must set it from the registry key,but t I'm not founding the file related to the font(PDF\ForceLargerFonts
)  in the registry file that must be changed

Comment: may this link helps you http://mdn.morovia.com/kb/Font-size-decreases-exporting-PDF-Crystal-Reports-10053.html

Comment: Me too facing the same issue !! Im using Crystal Reports XI.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue with Crystal Reports which reduces the font size when it exports to a PDF file. The solution is retrieved from Business Objects support site.
Solved it by below links is useful : 
please check it out

1- http://www.barcodesoft.com/crystal-reports-export-pdf-font-size.aspx

2- http://mdn.morovia.com/kb/Font-size-decreases-exporting-PDF-Crystal-Reports-10053.html

for other description : 
http://www.arcanadev.com/support/kb/K00000394.aspx

and Open the fonts folder and select "Font Settings." Make sure the "Hide fonts based on language settings" option is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, click on Start, Run, **Regedit**

1. Go to the following key HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business
   Objects\Crystal Reports For .Net Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\
2. Right click on the Export folder (if it doesn't exist then right click on Crystal Reports and select New, Key, enter **Export**)
3. Click on New, KEY, enter **Pdf**
4. Click on New, DWORD Value, enter **ForceLargerFonts**
5. After the above key is created, double click it and change the Value Data from **0 to 1**

Comment: how about 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

For `Crystal Reports for .NET Framework  v13.xx` For .net this registery patch worked. Just copy it to a text file , Name it `Crystall Report 13 PDF Large Fonts.reg` and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF]
"ForceLargerFonts"=dword:00000001
```